# Comparator gets indexes outside the bounds of the array in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, comparator

I'm trying to sort a vector `ord` with `ord.size() = 100` from the second element to the end:

```
sort(ord.begin() + 1, ord.end(), comp);
```

But function `comp()` gets `ord[101]`. **Why?**

---

`comp` listing:

```
bool comp(long long i, long long j){
    cout << i << " " << j << endl;
    return ((long long)x[i]-minx)*(y[j]-y[i]) <= ((long long)y[i]-minx_y)*(x[j]-x[i]);
}
```

part of `comp` output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAaUq.png

Comment: `comp` has to implement a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). Without knowing what is in `x` and `y` I can'y say for sure, but it seems extremely doubtful that this function satisfies those conditions.  Update your `cout` line to also show the value being returned and you will be able to spot which lines are inconsistent.

Comment: Using `<=` is a pretty good sign it's not strict weak ordering.

Comment: Yes, it was because comparator was bad. It didn't implement strict weak orderings. It even didn't have a distributive property.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool comp(long long i, long long j){
    std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
    return i < j;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    std::vector<long long int> ord;
    ord.reserve(100);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        ord.push_back( 101 - i );
    }

    std::sort(ord.begin() + 1, ord.end(), comp);

    return 0;
}
```

Works fine for me. I understand that it's not your exact code, but still.

Comment: Since the comparison violates the strict weak ordering requirement, this program is undefined. It "works" only through bad luck.